# How to select tab programmatically?

Tags: vmware-clarity

I need to switch from current tab to another without clicking on the tab itself.

Answer (score 0):

In [Clarity's documentation](https://vmware.github.io/clarity/documentation/v0.11/tabs), you can see that the `*clrIfActive` directive accepts a boolean input to force a tab to activate.

So in your case, just pass `true` to the `*clrIfActive` of the tab you want to programmatically select. How you do that depends on how you create your tab in the first place: statically, with an `*ngFor`, based on a specific tab model, ... We can't help you out more unless you provide an example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm getting the following error when trying to add clrIfActive.  Can you tell me which Clarity version supports it?  Thank you.  The error is  ------  Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'clrIfActive' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-template'.

Comment: `*clrIfActive` was introduced in v0.10.0 last year: https://vmware.github.io/clarity/news/0.10.0-alpha.5
You can read the release notes I linked to check the old syntax for tabs.